# Refresh second datepicker based on the first one

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am working on jQuery datepicker. There are two datepickers in my form. First one's minDate is set to current date & I want to set the minDate of the second datepicker to the date selected in first datepicker.

For the first time it works properly. But if the user picks another date in the first datepicker then second datepicker is not updated.

I've tried various onClick onBlur and refresh events but have not had any success. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.
the code I have written is as follows :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
var currentDate = new Date();
   var datePickerOptions1 = {
               dateFormat:'dd-M-yy',
                   minDate: currentDate};  

$('.datepick1').each(function(){    $(this).datepicker(datePickerOptions1);
});
//hover states on the static widgets
$('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
    function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); }, 
    function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }
);

});

function changeDate()
{
var tempDate = document.getElementById("date_1").value;
alert(tempDate+""+i);
 var datePickerOptions2 = {
           dateFormat:'dd-M-yy',
           minDate: tempDate };
$('.datepick2').each(function(){    $(this).datepicker(datePickerOptions2);
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373734/jquery-datepicker-restrict-dates-in-second-date-field-based-on-selected-date-in

find your answer here

Answer (score 0):

I've always used this piece of code for limiting the date range for 2 datepickers:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range

```
var dates = $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                    instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                    date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                        instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                        $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                        selectedDate, instance.settings );
                dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
            }
        });
```