# Jquery datepicker restrict dates in second date field based on selected date in first date field

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using Jquery date picker and I have the following code where when user selects a date, the field below is populated with date +1

```
$('#dt2').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy" 
    });

$("#dt1").datepicker(
    {dateFormat: "dd-M-yy", 
    minDate:  0,
onSelect: function(date){
var date2 = $('#dt1').datepicker('getDate');
            date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+1);
            $('#dt2').datepicker('setDate', date2);
```

I would like to restrict dates in `dt2` field which should not be below the date in `dt1` field. E.g. If date selected in `dt1` is `01-May-2013`, then user is allowed to pick date after `01-May-2013`, not less than `02-May-2013`

How can I restrict date picking in date field 2?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I created a jsfiddle for you.
I'm not a 100% sure if it's "foolproof" but to prevent users from manually typing a date you could set the inputs to `readonly`e.g.

```
<input type="text" id="dt1" readonly="readonly">
```

At the moment I check the dt2 onClose and if its date is below dt1s date I correct it.
Also if a date is selected in dt1 the [minDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) of dt2 is set to dt1 date +1.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#dt1").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function (date) {
            var date2 = $('#dt1').datepicker('getDate');
            date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
            $('#dt2').datepicker('setDate', date2);
            //sets minDate to dt1 date + 1
            $('#dt2').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date2);
        }
    });
    $('#dt2').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        onClose: function () {
            var dt1 = $('#dt1').datepicker('getDate');
            var dt2 = $('#dt2').datepicker('getDate');
            //check to prevent a user from entering a date below date of dt1
            if (dt2 <= dt1) {
                var minDate = $('#dt2').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
                $('#dt2').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

See the [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/PPSh3/3/)

Comment: +1, that was exactly what I needed. Instead of your last if in `#dt2` I added the readonly attribute to my input element.

Comment: @SirDerpington can this be done just with javascript? and input type date?

Comment: @IngusGraholskis I haven't had a real look but I guess it can be, yes. The input type date isn't supported by all major browsers yet though. Firefox for example lacks support if I'm correct. So you might want to give jQuery a go to have a reliable solution

Answer (score 19):

Here's how i do it --

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JDbdP/)

And the code is as follows

```
$('#dt2').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy" 
});

$("#dt1").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy", 
    minDate:  0,
    onSelect: function(date){            
        var date1 = $('#dt1').datepicker('getDate');           
        var date = new Date( Date.parse( date1 ) ); 
        date.setDate( date.getDate() + 1 );        
        var newDate = date.toDateString(); 
        newDate = new Date( Date.parse( newDate ) );                      
        $('#dt2').datepicker("option","minDate",newDate);            
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome answer.

Answer (score 5):

i just changed your code, so that min date for date2 set automatically & if date1 is greater than date2, it set date2=date1

```
  $("#dt1").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            onSelect: function (date) {
                var dt1 = $('#dt1').datepicker('getDate');
                var dt2 = $('#dt2').datepicker('getDate');
                if (dt1 > dt2) {
                    $('#dt2').datepicker('setDate', dt1);
                }
                $('#dt2').datepicker('option', 'minDate', dt1);
            }
        });
        $('#dt2').datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            minDate: $('#dt1').datepicker('getDate'),
            onClose: function () {
                var dt1 = $('#dt1').datepicker('getDate');
                var dt2 = $('#dt2').datepicker('getDate');
                //check to prevent a user from entering a date below date of dt1
                if (dt2 <= dt1) {
                    var minDate = $('#dt2').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
                    $('#dt2').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Even better - this seems like the right way to do this without annoying users.