# DatePicker set two dates with startDate >= tomorrow

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to build 2 datepickers with the following restriction:

1. startDate >= tomorrow
2. endDate > startDate
3. endDate can't select a date if startDate not selected

just like the checkin / checkout hotel rooms.
I'm using this so far

```
function customRange(input) 
{ 
    return {
     minDate: (input.id == "startDate" ? new Date(2008, 12 - 1, 1) : null),
     minDate: (input.id == "endDate" ? $("#startDate").datepicker("getDate") : null), 
     maxDate: (input.id == "startDate" ? $("#endDate").datepicker("getDate") : null)
   }; 
}
```

Can someone help me out in here?

Thanks

Comment: Check this link.This might be the answer for your question


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373734/jquery-datepicker-restrict-dates-in-second-date-field-based-on-selected-date-in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

1) First get today's and tomorrow's dates.

```
var today = new Date();
var tomorrow = new Date(today.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

2) Set tomorrow's date as **`minDate`** in `start` Date.

```
minDate: tomorrow
```

3) When you select a start date, set it as **`minDate`** for `end` Date.

```
onSelect: function (dat, inst) {
        $('#end').datepicker('option', 'minDate', dat);
    }
```

The entire thing is going to handle with *3 options* in Datepicker.

```
1. minDate  
2. maxDate  (if needed)
3. onSelect
```

---

```
$('#end').datepicker();
var today = new Date();
var tomorrow = new Date(today.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
console.log(tomorrow);
$('#start').datepicker({
    minDate: tomorrow,
    onSelect: function (dat, inst) {
        $('#end').datepicker('option', 'minDate', dat);
    }
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4azz9/)

Hope you understand.