# disable dates based on previously populated date using UI datePicker

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

i have a edit screen where in my start date and end date is pre-populated from database. The control is a UI datePicker plugin. I want to restrict/ disable the previous dates based on the start date which comes from the server. Also when i change the date, i want the end date to have a date starting from one day after the start date. Since the value gets populated first and the control is later added to the input field, im not able to control it.

Any help would be appreciated.
the code is as follows:

```
for(var i =0; i<abcd.length; i ++)
{
  $("#startDate input").val(StartDate);
  $("#endDate input").val(EndDate);
 $(".datePicker").datepicker();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code to set dynamic minimum and maximum date range.

```
 $("input.DateFrom").datepicker({
      beforeShow: customRange 
    });

function customRange(input) {
    //make use of parameter-input if you use this fuction more places
    //write some logic to deside min,max date and return
    var minimumDate = new Date();//or assign value from database and make sure date-format also
    var maximumDate = new Date();
    maximumDate.setDate(minimumDate.getDate()+20);

    return { minDate: minimumDate,
        maxDate: maximumDate
    };
}
```

Or ***if you want to set minimum date and maximum value as some constant range*** you can consider the below code:

```
    $("input.DateFrom").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: "+1M +10D" 
    });
```

[Reference: jQuery UI date picker min-max](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max)

[SO Answer-to restrict one date input based on other date input value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16374231/3186681)

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Manirajss/7tubwe2c/3/)