# Change date "datepicker" adding one day

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have 2 "datepicker" fields and I need to change the value of `'#checkout'` as soon as `'#chekin'` is changed. The value of `'#checkout'` should be `'#checking + 1 day'`. I need to put this code inside `'$( document ).ready(function() { ...});'`

I've found a code here but not working at all, no errors, but not working.

**js**:

```
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", 'dd/mm/yy' );

   $('#checkout').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-M-yy" });
   $('#checkin').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-M-yy" });

    $("#checkin").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy", 
        minDate:  0,
        onSelect: function(date){
            var date2 = $('#checkin').datepicker('getDate');
            date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+1);
            $('#checkout').datepicker('setDate', date2);
        }
    });
    </script>
```

**Html**:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" size="30" name="check_in_date" id="checkin">


<input type="text" class="datepicker" size="30" name="check_out_date" id="checkout">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373734/jquery-datepicker-restrict-dates-in-second-date-field-based-on-selected-date-in

Answer (score 0):

your code logic is ok however there is syntax error as below -

- you are missing closing `});` brackets at the end
- plus you are using `datepicker` for `#checkin` twice .

once with -

```
$('#checkin').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-M-yy" });
```

and other just below it like -

```
$("#checkin").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy", 
        minDate:  0,
        onSelect: function(date){
            var date2 = $('#checkin').datepicker('getDate');
            date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+1);
            $('#checkout').datepicker('setDate', date2);
        }
    });
```

Here is your [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ManojSalvi/7uyqkf3n/2/) and **edited code**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", 'dd/mm/yy' );

    $('#checkout').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-M-yy" });

    $("#checkin").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy", 
        minDate:  0,
        onSelect: function(date){
            var date2 = $('#checkin').datepicker('getDate');
            date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+1);
            $('#checkout').datepicker('setDate', date2);
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", 'dd/mm/yy' );
```

$('#checkout').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-M-yy" });
   $('#checkin').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-M-yy" });

```
$("#checkin").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onSelect: function (selected) {
        var dt = new Date(selected);
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
        $("#checkout").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
    }
});
$("#checkout").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onSelect: function (selected) {
        var dt = new Date(selected);
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
        $("#checkin").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
    }
});
});
</script>
```