# How to specified a date's range javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

```
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Solicitud De Vacaciones</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://formden.com/static/cdn/bootstrap-iso.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://formden.com/static/cdn/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <style>
    .bootstrap-iso .formden_header h2, .bootstrap-iso .formden_header p, .bootstrap-iso 
      form{
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: black
      }
    .bootstrap-iso form button, .bootstrap-iso form button:hover{
      color: white !important;
    } 
    .asteriskField{
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>              
  <div class="bootstrap-iso">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
      <form action="MovimientoBancario" class="form-horizontal" method="post">

         <div class="form-group ">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2 requiredField" for="date">
           Desde
           <span class="asteriskField">
            *
           </span>
          </label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
           <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
             <i class="fa fa-calendar">
             </i>
            </div>
            <input class="form-control" id="date" name="from" placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD" type="text" required/>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group ">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2 requiredField" for="date">
           Hasta
           <span class="asteriskField">
            *
           </span>
          </label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
           <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
             <i class="fa fa-calendar">
             </i>
            </div>
            <input class="form-control" id="date" name="to" placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD" type="text" required/>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>  

         <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
           <input name="_honey" style="display:none" type="text"/>
           <button class="btn btn-primary " name="submit" type="submit">
            Buscar
           </button>
          </div>
         </div>
      </form>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            var date_input=$('input[id="date"]');
            var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
            date_input.datepicker({
                format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                container: container,
                todayHighlight: true,
                autoclose: true,
            })

    })
  </script>
</body>
```

Here's my code, I've searched all over stackoverflow but none of the solutions I find works for me, I need to do two things.

1. date two has to be bigger than date one
2. date one has to give you the option to start from the current date.

I've tried these
[Jquery datepicker restrict dates in second date field based on selected date in first date field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373734/jquery-datepicker-restrict-dates-in-second-date-field-based-on-selected-date-in)
https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

Comment: Note that there are different `datepicker` plugins. You are using bootstrap datepicker. The links to other questions use jQueryUI datepicker. They each have different API's so solutions for one aren't applicable to the other

Comment: Where can I find links for those APIs?

Comment: Simple web search for "bootstrap datepicker"

Answer (score 0):

You can use startDate for restrict to start from current date.

Try below code I hope it will resolve your problem.

```
<html lang="es">

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Solicitud De Vacaciones</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://formden.com/static/cdn/bootstrap-iso.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://formden.com/static/cdn/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <style>
      .bootstrap-iso .formden_header h2,
      .bootstrap-iso .formden_header p,
      .bootstrap-iso form {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: black
      }

      .bootstrap-iso form button,
      .bootstrap-iso form button:hover {
        color: white !important;
      }

      .asteriskField {
        color: red;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="bootstrap-iso">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
            <form action="MovimientoBancario" class="form-horizontal" method="post">

              <div class="form-group ">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2 requiredField" for="date">
           Desde
           <span class="asteriskField">
            *
           </span>
          </label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                      <i class="fa fa-calendar">
             </i>
                    </div>
                    <input class="form-control" class="from_date" id="dpd1" name="from" placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD" type="text" required/>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group ">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2 requiredField" for="date">
           Hasta
           <span class="asteriskField">
            *
           </span>
          </label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                      <i class="fa fa-calendar">
             </i>
                    </div>
                    <input class="form-control" id="dpd2" name="to" placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD" type="text" required/>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                  <input name="_honey" style="display:none" type="text" />
                  <button class="btn btn-primary " name="submit" type="submit">
            Buscar
           </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" />

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var date_input = $('input[id="date"]');
        var container = $('.bootstrap-iso form').length > 0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
        var currDate = new Date();
        var date = new Date();
        date.setDate(date.getDate());
        $('#dpd1').datepicker({
          format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
          startDate: date,
          container: container,
          todayHighlight: true,
          autoclose: true,
        })

        $('#dpd1').datepicker().on('changeDate', function() {
          $('#dpd2').val('')
        })


        $('#dpd2')
          .datepicker()
          .on('show', function(ev) {
            var toDate = $('#dpd1').datepicker("getDate");
            toDate.setDate(toDate.getDate() + 1);
            $('#dpd2').datepicker("setStartDate", toDate);
          })
          .on('changeDate', function(ev) {
            var date1 = $('#dpd1').datepicker("getDate").valueOf();
            var date11 = $('#dpd1').datepicker("getDate");
            date11.setDate(date11.getDate() + 1);
            var date2 = ev.date.valueOf();
            if (date2 <= date1) {
              alert("Second date bigger than first!");
              $('#dpd2').datepicker("setDate", date11);
            }

          });

      })

    </script>
  </body>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jPUBv/159/)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you have used same `id` on both textboxes with different `name` attributes. It is good practice to use different ids for all controls.

Regardless of that, here's the change you need to make in your jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var date_input = $('input[name="from"]');
  var date1_input = $('input[name="to"]');
  var container =
    $(".bootstrap-iso form").length > 0
      ? $(".bootstrap-iso form").parent()
      : "body";
  date_input
    .datepicker({
      format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
      container: container,
      todayHighlight: true,
      autoclose: true,
      startDate: new Date()
    })
    .on("changeDate", function(e) {
      var desdeDate = e.date;
      desdeDate.setDate(desdeDate.getDate() + 1);
      date1_input.datepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        autoclose: true
      });
      date1_input.datepicker("setStartDate", desdeDate);
      date1_input.focus();
    });
});
```

Note that I used name attributes to select the textboxes and `changeDate` event is to calculate the new start date value for the second textbox which is then initialized with `setStartDate` method of the datepicker plugin.

You can find many other options to tweak at [their website](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html).